# KStream-KTable Inner Join Lost Messages with Exactly Once Config

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When I do not set **processing.gurantee** which means stream will be started with its default value (**at_least_once**), this code can log successfully and send joined messages to relevant topic.

When the **exactly_once** config is **enabled** on this same stream application, some of the data are not able to pass through join successfully. Even there are logs for the first peek block, I can not see some of the second peek logs and some of the messages that I need to have.

I'm sure that both kstream and ktable have required values to be which are not null. And both side gets messages regularly.

**Stream Configs:**

- processing.guarantee=exactly_once
- replication.factor=3 (this increases replication factor for internal topics)

**Kafka (with 3 broker) Details:**

- version=2.2.0
- log.roll.ms=3600000
- offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
- transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
- transaction.state.log.min.isr=3
- message.max.bytes=2000024

Question is, How **exactly_once** processing guarantee setting can cause this kind of situation?

```
final KStream<String, UserProfile> userProfileStream = builder.stream(TOPIC_USER_PROFILE);
final KTable<String, Device> deviceKTable = builder.table(TOPIC_DEVICE);

userProfileStream
.peek((genericId, userProfile) ->
    log.debug("[{}] Processing user profile: {}", openUserId, userProfile)
)
.join(
    deviceKTable,
    (userProfile, device) -> {
        userProfile.setDevice(device);

        return userProfile;
    },
    Joined.with(Serdes.String(), userProfileSerde, deviceSerde)
)
.peek((genericId, userProfile) ->
    log.debug("[{}] Updated user profile: {}", genericId, userProfile)
)
.to(TOPIC_UPDATED_USER_PROFILE, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), userProfileSerde));
```